# How to Filter Datagrid values using TextBox (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, database, datagrid

I'm having some trouble in filtering datagrid values (from database) using Textbox. Indeed i'm new in WPF C#, and i need some help in this case.

[image]

This is my XAML:

```
<Button Name="btnSelect"
        Content="Select All"
        Height="30"
        Width="80"
        Margin="4"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Click="btn_SelectUser"/>
    <DataGrid Name="dtgUser" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="380" Width="684" 
              Margin="10,54,0,0"/>
```

Here is my Code Behind to select values from database after button Select is pressed:

```
private void btn_SelectUser(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            _con = new SqlConnection(_strConn);
            try
            {
                _con.Open();
                string query = "select id_int_user, name_str_user  from tbl_user";
                _cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _con);
                _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                _adp = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
                _dt = new DataTable("tbl_user");
                _adp.Fill(_dt);
                dtgUser.ItemsSource = _dt.DefaultView;
                _adp.Update(_dt);

                _con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

And this is to select just edited value in textbox.How to implement this method? (Note: I need bring values from database via datagrid):

```
private void txt_SearchUser(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Here is my difficulty //I know nothing how to do it.
    }
```

Comment: The `DataGrid` 's `ItemsSource` would let you put data in it, however, it only takes `IEnumerable<T>` so you might want to find a work around about it.

Comment: why are you returning all values from the database?  if the value has already been entered why not add a where clause to your SQL query?

Comment: @Nikerym He used the `Update` to put data into the `DataTable`. I assume he want to query them all and filter it from the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method may not be the best way to populate a DataGrid (you may want to use [data binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#dataset) in the future), but here are some quick tricks for your situation:

1) If the user needs to click the Select All button first, then filter the data by ID:

```
private void txt_SearchUser(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable tempDt = _dt.Copy();
    tempDt.Clear();
    if (txt_Search.Text != "") // Note: txt_Search is the TextBox..
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in _dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dr["id_int_user"].ToString() = txt_Search.Text)
            {
                tempDt.ImportRow(dr);
            }
        }
        dtgUser.ItemsSource = tempDt.DefaultView;
    }
    else
    {
        dtgUser.ItemsSource = _dt.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

2) If you want to filter data from database every time the user put an ID into the search box (without clicking the Select All button first):

```
private void txt_SearchUser(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _con = new SqlConnection(_strConn);
    try
    {
        _con.Open();
        string query = "select id_int_user, name_str_user from tbl_user";
        if(txt_Search.Text != "") // Note: txt_Search is the TextBox..
        {
            query += " where id_int_user = " + txt_Search.Text;
        }
        _cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _con);
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        _adp = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
        _dt = new DataTable("tbl_user");
        _adp.Fill(_dt);
        dtgUser.ItemsSource = _dt.DefaultView;
        _adp.Update(_dt);

        _con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use this code when user starts input ID at textbox automatically datagrid show results according ID on textbox. How to do this Without press a button?

Comment: If that is what you need, then I think the 2nd example in this answer should work for you.

Comment: yes the 2nd example is near answer that i need. But when i enter a valid id nothing happen.

Comment: Hmm.. That's strange.. The example is basically just adds a where clause to your original code. So if your `btn_SelectUser` function works, this should works. You have registered it as the TextChanged event handler, right? i.e. `<TextBox x:Name="txt_Search" TextChanged="txt_SearchUser" />` ?

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Just Putting `TextChanged = "txt_SearchUser"` in XAML.

Comment: Good to know that. By the way, you may also need to add some input validations on that TextBox. e.g. don't process anything if user input non-integer values, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use `ICollectionView` for `DataGrid.ItemsSource` in the View Model and set `Filter` to filter the items.

First, prepare a collection object (e.g. `ObservableCollection<YourItemClass>`) and define `SourceItems` in the View Model:

```
public ICollectionView SourceItems {
  get {
    return _sourceItems 
      ?? (_sourceItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_source));
  }
}
```

Then in response to some events, add filtering predicate to filter the items in View:

```
var items = (ListCollectionView)SourceItems;
items.Filter = obj => obj.UserName == user_name_for_filter;
```

And of course, set binding.

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <local:YourViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding SourceItems} ... />
```